# Image gets abnormally scaled when hovering on other images

Tags: html, css, image

I have a site which has a couple of images and I implemented a hover effect on the images but for some reason, one of my other images (in another div scales up and gets misaligned). I thought this might be because of some conflicting classes. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Since, I might have to upload the code for the whole site. I've uploaded it on a JSFiddle.
Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/40swprv2/7/

Here's the error causing code

```css
.tile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.tile:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

The code causing the error is in style.css line 263 - 303 of the JSFiddle. I've commented it out for now so u can see the result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the margin you have placed on the images?

Comment: it maybe because of that, but the problem is the image is getting scaled up abnormally. Comment out the code in JSFiddle and see for yourself

Comment: I'm not seeing any scaling issues.

Comment: did u comment out the code?

Comment: I'm not seeing it either, I modified the codes as described. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes and still unable to replicate.

Comment: I'm using firefox and just to be clear, the image that gets scaled is the one in the first div, the one next to the "Mahtama Gandhi" Text. Are you still unable to replicate the glitch?

Comment: That image isn't loading in the fiddle. You really need to make a **smaller demo** of just this issue.

Comment: hmmm, alright ill do something, gimme a sec

Comment: Alright, I've shrunk dosn the html, please have a look

Comment: @Paulie_D i've made the error occur by default now

Comment: to see the expected output, comment out the code mentioned above